# Alamofire and ObjectMapper to TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I am new to swift and trying to fetch json from an api and show it to UITableView but it won't show.

This is the json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "user_id": "somestringhere",
    "devices": [
        {
            "id": "somestringhere",
            "source": "somestringhere",
            "source_text": "somestringhere",
            "logo_url": "somestringhere",
            "is_connected": "0"
        },
        {
```

For mapping the json data:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Devices: Mappable {
required init?(map: Map) {
}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id<-map["id"]
        source<-map["source"]
        sourceText<-map["source_text"]
        logo<-map["logo_url"]
        isConnected<-map["is_connected"]  
    }
   
    var id : String?
    var source : String?
    var sourceText : String?
    var logo : String?
    var isConnected : Bool?
    
}
```

My Controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var devices : [Devices]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        tableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return devices?.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        
        cell.setup(title: "\(devices?[indexPath.row].sourceText)", iconLink: "\(devices?[indexPath.row].logo)")
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    
    func loadData(){
        let base = Config().base
        let endPoint = Config.EndPoint()
        let patientId = User().id
            
                let url = base + endPoint.showDevices
                let header: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                ]
                let params: Parameters = [
                    "patient_id" : patientId
                ]
                
                let code = Code(id: id)
                AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:header).validate()
                    .response{ (response) in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(let value):
                            let json = JSON(value)
                           
                          self.devices = Mapper<Devices>().mapArray(JSONString: json.rawString()!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                           
                         case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)
  }
 }    
}
}
```

I tried printing the device variable after the Mapper

```
self.devices = Mapper<PatientDevices>().mapArray(JSONString: json.rawString()!)
print(self.devices)
```

and shows me

```
Optional([ProjectName.Devices])
```

I tried to print json response data and request successful however I couldn't add it to tableview.
What should I do to solve this problem?
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all  – as always – since Swift 4 libraries like `ObjectMapper` and `SwiftyJSON` have become obsolete in favor of built-in, efficient `Codable` protocol. Avoid tutorials which suggest those outdated libraries.

Regarding your mistake you are ignoring the root object, the object with keys `success`, `user_id` and `devices`.

This is a solution using `Decodable`

- Drop `SwiftyJSON` and `ObjectMapper`
- Replace the structs with

  ```
    struct Root : Decodable {
        let success : Bool
        let userId : String
        let devices : [Device]
    }

    struct Device : Decodable {
        let id : String
        let source : String
        let sourceText : String
        let logoUrl : URL
        let isConnected : String // this value is String, not Bool
    }
  ```
- Replace `loadData` with

  ```
    func loadData(){
        let base = Config().base
        let endPoint = Config.EndPoint()
        let patientId = User().id

        let url = base + endPoint.showDevices
        let header: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        ]
        let params: Parameters = [
            "patient_id" : patientId
        ]

        let code = Code(id: id)
        AF.request(url, parameters: params, headers:header).validate()
            .responseData { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        do {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                            let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                            self.devices = result.devices
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } catch { print(error) }

                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                }
        }
    }
  ```

  The Alamofire response returns raw data and the `keyDecodingStrategy` converts the *snake_cased* keys to *camelCased* struct members and `logoUrl` is decoded as `URL`
- Finally rename the data source array to

  ```
    var devices = [Device]()
  ```

  and remove all question marks after `devices`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the main object. Add this class in addition to your Device class.

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Response: Mappable {

    required init?(map: Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        success<-map["success"]
        user_id<-map["user_id"]
        devices<-map["devices"]
    }

    var success : Bool?
    var user_id : String?
    var devices: [Device]?

}
```

Also create a new variable to map the main object

```
var response: Response?
```

and change

```
self.devices = Mapper<Devices>().mapArray(JSONString: json.rawString()!)
```

to

```
self.response = Mapper<Response>().map(JSONString: json.rawString()!)
self.devices = self.response.devices
```

Comment: Thanks I will do this to my projects from now on.